# Base64 safe url on Swift

Tags: swift, basic-authentication, encode

I'm trying to send a `base64` string who is a `sandbox-key`, the problem is that `Postman` has encrypted different comparison with `Swift`. Here's the result...

```
originalString = "sk_289d8dd8e721484c9c8c63e39899cf90"

postmanBase64 = "c2tfMjg5ZDhkZDhlNzIxNDg0YzljOGM2M2UzOTg5OWNmOTA6"

swiftBase64 = "c2tfMjg5ZDhkZDhlNzIxNDg0YzljOGM2M2UzOTg5OWNmOTA="
```

Do you have any ideas to fix this?, why Postman encode different?

Swift Encoding:

```
 let authHeader = "sk_289d8dd8e721484c9c8c63e39899cf90".base64Encoded()!
            
 let authHeaderBase64 = toggleBase64URLSafe(item: authHeader, on: true)
            
  public extension String {
    func base64Encoded() -> String? {
        return data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString()
    }
  }
  
    func toggleBase64URLSafe(item: String, on: Bool) -> String {
        if on {
            // Make base64 string safe for passing into URL query params
            let base64url = item.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "_")
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "-")
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: "")
            return base64url
        } else {
            // Return to base64 encoding
            var base64 = item.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "/")
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "+")
            // Add any necessary padding with `=`
            if base64.count % 4 != 0 {
                base64.append(String(repeating: "=", count: 4 - base64.count % 4))
            }
            return base64
        }
    }
```

ps. My request works if I use `postmanBase64`

This is my postman output to translate my request into swift code
as you can see, this value has been translated automatically

[image]

Comment: Postman can generate Swift code, maybe they show how they translate it?

Comment: Postman translated my string automatically

Comment: just decode the Postman generated Base64 and you see it is actually one character more:  `sk_289d8dd8e721484c9c8c63e39899cf90:`

Comment: That's right jps, well done, it has an extra character (:)

Comment: Also, that value seems to be into Headers, so why translate differently + & /? In URL, I would have percent escape them.

Comment: From the added screenshot I get an idea about what is going on. That value is part of a Basic Authorization header. Basic Auth is a scheme in which you send a Base64 encoded string that consists of `username:password`. In your case Postman takes the key `sk_289d8dd8e721484c9c8c63e39899cf90` as username and adds `:` plus nothing and encodes it. That's how you get `c2tfMjg5ZDhkZDhlNzIxNDg0YzljOGM2M2UzOTg5OWNmOTA6`

Comment: [*a request contains a header field in the form of Authorization: Basic <credentials>, where credentials is the Base64 encoding of ID and password joined by a single colon :.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Comment: @jps: _URL_ often does use 'base64url' aka 'URL-safe base64' with -_ instead of +/ and often without padding, to avoid need for percent-encoding, and JSON signing/encrypting (JOSE/JWS/JWE/JWT) also does so; see RFC4648. But Basic-Auth does not, it uses traditional (MIME) base64, and does not need percent-encoding because it is not a URL.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes, I know. I'm just not sure why you tell me that. I didn't mention Base64Url anywhere.